# How to Extract List of Text File Values Between 2 Identifiers That are Used Several Times

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, text-files, extract

I am trying to make a VB.NET Visual Studio 2019 form that will ask for a text file and output a list of names in a TextBox I have called `TextBox4` so I don't have to create any files (or maybe create a text file, copy it to TextBox4, then delete it?). The names from a text file are between `"Customer_Name"` and `"Customer_ID"`. The file doesn't seem to have any rhyme or reason other than those 2 identifiers, so splitting it up efficiently has been tough. There are generally between 100 and 1000 entries per file if that is relevant.

**Sample (mock) data:**
`"Customer_name":"JOHN DOE","Customer_id":"9251954","Customer_team_id":"HOST","Customer_position_id":"MGR","Customer_short_name":"Joey","Customer_eligibility":"LT5","Customer_page_url":"google.com","Customer_alt_id":"M7","Customer_name":"JANE DOE","Customer_id":"8734817","Customer_team_id":"HOST","Customer_position_id":"TECH","Customer_name":"JOSEPH DOE","Customer_id":"8675307",`

**I would want to show this in the text box:**
JOHN DOE
JANE DOE
JOSEPH DOE

Comment: Could you provide an example of the text file, even if it is with mock data?

Comment: Added to main question body text above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this regular expression pattern:

```
(?:")(?<key>\w+)(?:":")(?<value>((\w|\s|\.))+)(?:",)
```

This does several things:

1. `(?:")` - create non-capturing group to match the open quotation mark
2. `(?<key>\w+)` - create a named group to match the key (e.g. Customer_name)
3. `(?:":")` - create a non-capturing group to match the close quotation mark, colon, and open quotation mark
4. `(?<value>((\w|\s|\.))+)` - create a named group to match the value (e.g. John Doe)
5. `(?:",)` - create a non-capturing group to match the close quotation mark

With this, you can loop over the matches and the matches' groups to get just the customer names:

```vb
' declare the pattern and input (escaping quotation marks) as well as a collection to store just the customer_name values
Dim pattern As String = "(?:"")(?<key>\w+)(?:"":"")(?<value>((\w|\s|\.))+)(?:"",)"
Dim input As String = """Customer_name"":""JOHN DOE"",""Customer_id"":""9251954"",""Customer_team_id"":""HOST"",""Customer_position_id"":""MGR"",""Customer_short_name"":""Joey"",""Customer_eligibility"":""LT5"",""Customer_page_url"":""google.com"",""Customer_alt_id"":""M7"",""Customer_name"":""JANE DOE"",""Customer_id"":""8734817"",""Customer_team_id"":""HOST"",""Customer_position_id"":""TECH"",""Customer_name"":""JOSEPH DOE"",""Customer_id"":""8675307"""
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
Dim names As New List(Of String)()

' loop over each match
For Each match As Match In matches
    ' loop over each group in the match
    For index As Integer = 0 To match.Groups.Count - 1
        Dim group As Group = match.Groups.Item(index)

        ' only do something if we're on the "key" group, the "key" group's value is Customer_name, and there's at least one more group left
        If (group.Name = "key" AndAlso group.Value = "Customer_name" AndAlso index < match.Groups.Count - 1)
            ' only do something if the next group is the "value" group
            Dim valueGroup As Group = match.Groups.Item(index + 1)
            If (valueGroup.Name = "value") Then
                ' add the key's value
                names.Add(valueGroup.Value)
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next

' set the TextBox's lines
TextBox4.Lines = names.ToArray()
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zja46U

Edit - keep in mind that because we're using named groups, this code can be expanded to get any key/value pair now. It is just for the sake of this example that I'm getting only the `Customer_name` key/value pair.

Comment: The fiddle works like I want, thank you! But I get an error in Visual Studio about the "Group.Name" in the IF statements that "Name" is not a member of "Group"

Comment: @Mike - The Group.Name property was introduced in .NET framework 4.7. What version are you targeting?

Comment: @Mike - Setup a breakpoint on `TextBox4.Lines = names.ToArray()` and check what the value of `names` is. If it contains values then you may need to manually refresh the UI by using `TextBox4.Refresh()` or `TextBox4.Invalidate(True)`

Comment: Actually I lied, it works fine. Thank you!!

Comment: @Mike - no problem, please remember to upvote and accept as answer. Doing that adds to my total reputation.

Comment: I did find an issue with some names. There are a handful of people with dashes in there names as well as single quotes. Something like JOHN DOE-SMITH gets skipped over and JOE D'OLIVERA gets skipped over as well. Otherwise, it handles periods like "Jr." fine.

Comment: You will need to tweak the value named group to account for those: `(?<value>(([\w\s\.\-']))+)` the one in this comment says any words, space, dots, hyphens, or apostrophes.